# getting null values from bean

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am trying to understand autowiring in beans , I am able to autowire but still getting null values here is code snippets

**Edited entire code with current output**

```
 @Component
public class A {
    private String value;
    private B b;

    public void display() {
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(b.m());
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }


    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

B class

```
@Component
public class B {

    private String b;

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String m() {
        return b;
    }

}
```

**configuration.java**

```
@Service
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = A.class)
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    public A setBean() {
        A a = new A();
        a.setValue("inside A");
        return a;
    }

    @Autowired
    public B setB() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setB("inside B");
        return b;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext configApplicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                AppConfig.class);
        A app = (A) configApplicationContext.getBean("a");
        app.display();
    }

}
```

Now the question is, I am supposed to get all values but instead of that I am getting null value from each bean ,
So why I am getting this value as null and how can I sort this?

**Edit**

the output is

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>   null null

**Edit** After debugging it i found that , in config class it is passing values as specified but when it comes to display values in `display()` it gives null

Comment: What are the package names of your classes?

Comment: That is the package Name or the Folder structure?

Comment: my classes are in `java` package and the folder str is `test.java.A` (`A` is class)

Comment: @Jens did i miss anything?

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "*.java" })` must be in a `@Configuration` annotated file not in an `@Service` annotated file.

Comment: Also your package Name Looks strange

Comment: changed `@Serivice` to `@Configuration` still getting error

Comment: the idea for this package name is like I am specifying a middle folder name , so I can do complex cofiguration but changing it to simple still gets the null value

Comment: and when  I apply `@required` i get exception of null values in car.class

Comment: I would guess, `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "*.java" })` is not working. Try `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "test.java" })`

Comment: @SergeBallesta stack trace is fine and even constructor with debug statement is working

Comment: I even tried a new project , still getting same output

Comment: The code you've posted here can't produce the output you've posted. You print the value of `b.m()` which means that since you actually get any output `B` is autowired (otherwise you'd get an NPE), but since you initialize *all* instances of B with `value="some value"` `b.m()` *will* return `"some value"`. Additionally, your main class doesn't compile since you've put the method body directly in the class and in the comments you talk about *car.class* which is never mentioned in the question. Please post the *actual* code you're running.

Comment: @Raniz I made the edit.. please check

Comment: well it looks like your `A` and `B` classes are instantiated twice......

Comment: yeah , just removed the `@component` annotation and replaced it with bean in configuration class solved the error

Comment: @AntJavaDev can u help me to figure out , that how i can use `@component` to instantiate bean once..(any hint will be good)

Comment: it seams there is an issue with the config of the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` , it overrides the bean definition , so first you proper init the `A,B` classes based on the `AppConfig` class , and then again it picks them up by the package context scan thus overriding your beans properties

Comment: oo well change the `@Autowired` annotations in the `AppConfig` class with the `@Bean` annotation , as suggested by @deepdownunder2222 , check a proper tutorial and read it carefully , also in order to get the actual bean created by `AppConfig` i dont think that the method `configApplicationContext.getBean("a");` is correct......

Comment: actually when I removed `@component` , it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you've not quite grasped the difference between `@Autowired`, `@Bean`, and `@Component`.

- `@Autowired` means that a field or method should be set to or called with autowired (injected) beans.
- `@Bean` is used in a class marked with `@Configuration` to tell Spring about a bean that can be autowired
- `@Component` is used on a class to tell Spring that this class should be instantiated as a bean that can be autowired.

In your code you've marked both *A* and *B* as `@Component`s which means that they will be instantiated as beans using their default constructors, using default values.

You've then tried to instantiate these as beans (again) in *AppConfig* but used `@Autowired` to mark the definitions which means that Spring won't pick them up.

You need to choose *one* way if telling Spring about your beans, so you can either remove `@Component` from *A* and *B* and use `@Bean` instead of `@Autowired` on the methods that create them in *AppConfig*, or remove the bean definitions completely from *AppConfig* and initialise the members inside *A* and *B* upon construction.

First option:

```
// No @Component here
public class A {
    ...
}

// No @Component here
public class B {
    ...
}

@Configuration
// You probably don't need @ComponentScan anymore since
// no classes are annotated with @Component
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = A.class)
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public A setBean() {
        A a = new A();
        a.setValue("inside A");
        return a;
    }

    @Bean
    public B setB() {
        B b = new B();
        b.setB("inside B");
        return b;
    }
}
```

Second option:

```
@Component
public class A {
    private String value = "inside A";
    ...
}

@Component
public class B {
    private String b = "inside B";
    ...
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = A.class)
public class AppConfig {
    // No bean definitions here, but required for @ComponentScan
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution to your updated question

Comment: actually I was mixing two approaches , ie by `@component` and by `@confuguration` was causing ambugity now , i know what to do in either of situtation, BTW Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes of your receiving `null` values:

1. `@Component` should be written with a capital letter and the proper annotation from the Spring package must be imported;
2. Class 'ApCfg' should look like this:

   ```
   @Configuration // this annotation is needed by Spring to know it is a config class
   @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "java" }) // you have to add the package NAMES here, not a regex
   public class ApCfg {

   @Bean // here, you're telling Spring to register a bean in its container, so you have to mark it as so, by using the @Bean annotation
   public A getA() {
       A a = new A(); // constructors are methods too, so they need to be called, using paranthesis
       a.setAValue("asdf"); // setters usually return void, so you shouldn't be able to return this
       return a; // this instance here is what will be registered in the container
    }
   }
   ```

If you've annotated class `A` with `@Component`, then you shouldn't be able to register it twice, so you should choose a way - either use the @Component annotation, or define it manually in the Config class in a method annotated by @Bean.

Also, I tend to agree that your choice of package name is rather peculiar. Are you certain that the package definition at the top of your classes is:

```
package java;
```

?

If you don't have any statement starting with the word `package`, then all you're classes are in the `default` package and, in that case, I strongly recommend grouping them in real packages instead.

Comment: `package test.java` and I am still getting same output

Comment: now I got the point, you were right , i was calling `A & B` twice one by `@component` and other by `@configuration`

Comment: @themountain, `package test;`, not `package test.java`. `.java` is a *file* extension that you should use for the files in which you write the class definitions (these are the ones that get compiled). I recommend that you skim the Packages chapter in the official Java tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html. It is concise and is certain to clear things up. :)

Comment: thanks for tip, but i already use like `package com.java.test.somepackage` that never caused any trouble but i'll take care of it (you increased my workload lol ;) ) 
BTW thanks for the tip :)